# How to resolve phpunit version difference errors?

Tags: java, selenium, phpunit

I have selenium test scripts which are exported in `phpunit` from `Selenium IDE`. And when I run them with `selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar` and `PHPUnit 5.3.4` by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors, on on centos(textMode).

I always get following errors:

> 1. BadMethodCallException: The command 'open' is not existent or not supported yet.
> 2. PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long.

How to resolve these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are not extending *Selenium2TestCase* class in your phpunit code. Because it doesnot support open and other commands.

Comment: yes I'm extending Selenium2TestCase class only, because otherwise it gives class not found error to SeleniumTestCase class with my current php version

Comment: @Pampserver any fix for this? I'm on phpunit 4.x because of laravel